# Quadrature rule for adaptive scheme with reuse

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I want to integrate a funktion, which is every slow to evaluate and spiky. Therefore I want to use an adaptive scheme.

I would like my subintervals to reuse the points I already calculated. I can only think of the trapezoidal rule, where the rule involves two points only. Is there any higher order rule where I do not discard points I already calculated?

The way I understand Gauss–Kronrod and Clenshaw–Curtis they only reuse the points if I don't change the interval. Is there any method, where I the same points for the inital interval and my subintervals?